# .net Appdomain can't attach AssemblyResolve

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop, directory-structure, appdomain

I wrote a simple program that consists of an executable in vb6 and 2 dlls one written in vb.net (testpi.dll) and the other c# (PlugIn1.dll).

The vb6 exe has a reference to the testpi.dll,
the testpi.dll has a reference to the Plugin1.dll

the Plugin1.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using CommonInterface;


namespace PlugIn1
{
    
    [Serializable]
    public class PlugIn : MarshalByRefObject, IPlugIn
    {
        
        private Dictionary<string,RuleHandle > dHandleRules= new Dictionary<string,RuleHandle>();
        private string name;
        
        public string Name { get { return name; } }

       
        public void Initialize()
        {
            name = "PlugIn 1";            
                }

        

        public object GetHandle(string Name, ref string msgErr) {
            msgErr = "";

            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) return null;
                if (dHandleRules == null) return null;

                dHandleRules.TryGetValue(Name, out var handle);
                return handle;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msgErr = Error(ex, "PlugIn.LoadAssembly");
            }
            return null;
        }



        public object LoadAssembly(string sInput, string RuleName, string sPrefixClassName, ref string msgErr) {
            RuleHandle hR = null;
            msgErr = "";

            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(sInput))
                {
                    Byte[] rawAssembly = LoadFile(sInput);
                    Assembly assemblyr = Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);

                    //String sPrefixClassName = GetClassPrefix(TypeRule);
                    Type TypeR = assemblyr.GetType("MyScript." + sPrefixClassName + RuleName);
                    Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(TypeR);

                    hR = new RuleHandle(TypeR, instance);

                    if (dHandleRules == null) dHandleRules = new Dictionary<string, RuleHandle>();    
                    if (dHandleRules.ContainsKey(RuleName)) dHandleRules.Remove(RuleName);
                    dHandleRules.Add(RuleName, hR);

                }
                else {
                    msgErr = "FILE NON TROVATO:" + sInput; 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msgErr=Error(ex, "PlugIn.LoadAssembly");
            }
            return hR;
        }

        private byte[] LoadFile(String filename) {
            Byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            return buffer;            
        }

        private string Error(Exception ex,string procedure) { 
            return  procedure + "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();            
        }


        public void FinalizeInterface() {
            if (dHandleRules != null) dHandleRules.Clear();
            dHandleRules = null;
        }

        ~PlugIn()
        {
            FinalizeInterface();
        }
    }
}
```

the vb6 exe program consist a Form with a button. Below the code of click event of the button:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()  
   Dim obj As Object  
   Set obj = New testpi.tClass1  
   obj.TESTClick
End Sub
```

where testpi is a vb.net dll com compatible compiled for x86 CPU.

Below testpi.dll

```
Imports System.Reflection

<Serializable>
Public Class tClass1

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
   MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub

Public sub TESTClick() 
        Dim setup As AppDomainSetup = New AppDomainSetup() With {
            .ApplicationName = "PlugIn1",
            .ConfigurationFile = "PlugIn1" & ".dll.config",
            .ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
        }
    
        Dim appDm As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(setup.ApplicationName,          
                                 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup)
    
        AddHandler appDm.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf AssemblyResolve
End sub    

End Class
```

the line `AddHandler appDm.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf AssemblyResolve` raises error:

> unresolved type for member testpi.tclass1, testpi, version 1.0.0.0,
> Culture newutral PublicKeyToken = null

how can I solve this problem ?